# Ways to resolve method from name and signature

Tags: c#, reflection, expression, reflection.emit

If you have a method name and an array of parameter types (a signature), you can use reflection to get a MethodInfo and invoke the method.

```
MethodInfo info = myObj.GetType().GetMethod("MethodName", new object[] { typeof(string), typeof(int) });

info.Invoke(myObj, new object[] {"Hello", 22});
```

Invoking a MethodInfo in this manner is very slow.  To speed it up, we can create a map that has wrappers to the MethodInfo that invoke the method using the Expression API or using Reflection.Emit.

However, doing so requires that we maintain a map of signatures to MethodInfo wrappers.  To do this, we need a "key" that represents the Name+Signature so we can quickly find the required MethodWrapper from our map (if it exists) when trying to invoke a method.  I'm looking for suggestions on how to generate that key.  Currently, I'm contemplating simply concatenating the MethodName with the name of each type in the signature to generate a key, but this seems slow to me.

Looking for advice on better options.

EDIT:

Suppose I have a method with one parameter:

```
DoSomething(object parameter);
```

The signature is "DoSomething" + typeof(object)

No suppose I pass in the signature "DoSomething" + typeof(SomeTypeThatDerivesFromObject)

These signatures should "match".

Comment: Create a type that has properties for its name and param types and then implement the comparable interface for it to perform the search comparison.

Comment: I don't think IComparable works for Dictionary lookups.  I guess the basic problem is I need to implement a version of GetHashCode() and Equals.  Restating the question, what are some good strategies for generating the HashCode?

Comment: `XOR` (`^`) the `GetHashCode` from your properties.

Comment: Doesnt it auto hash for keys in a hashtable anyway ie key->hashed key -> lookup in table. If so wont it be just as quick with a string as a prehash version?

Comment: @M.Babcock, see edits above.  Not sure XOR would work for this situation (to be fair, nor would my initial concatenated string solution)

Comment: @LukeMcGregor - I think you're right. That would be a good optimization.

Comment: @JoeEnzminger - Rather than just hashing the properties of the current object you could calculate the hash based on all of the properties of the current type (using `Type.GetProperties` or possibly even `Type.GetMembers`) though in the end a pre-hashed string comparison would probably be quicker.

Comment: Personally i would use a string as the key, and i would make it look as much like the actual sig as possible (ie use the following key syntax 'DoSomething(object,int,string)' I dont think this will pose any kind of perf issue and it will make your life easier debugging